# Possible to route gameserver traffic through cloudflare?

Tags: reverse-proxy, ddos, cloudflare

I use cloudflare for my website and we have a gameserver I was wondering if it is possible to route traffic through cloudflare.

This recently sprung into my head when I realized that I could route Shoutcast through another of cloudflares port (8080) which does not do any performance enhancing or anything it just acts as a reverse proxy and stops DDoS.

I then tried by setting up a subdomain with my gameserver IP cloudflared and then pinged the IP and Port. It seems to have connections but when actually connecting via the game it doesnt.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

No; Cloudflare only works for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the "orange" cloud, on the sub domain you setup you should be able to access the port even though the domain itself is being hosted via CloudFlare. The orange cloud is the service mode setting for CloudFlare, it's basically an on/off switch.

> An orange cloud means that your web traffic will pass through the CloudFlare system making your site faster, safer and smarter. A gray cloud means that your traffic will not pass through the CloudFlare system.

[Source](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169626-What-subdomains-are-appropriate-for-orange-gray-clouds-)